# No idea, My game keeps crashing on phones - Null Pointer Dereference

Tags: crash, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, null-pointer

Please help, I have no idea what I am doing.

I made a game on Unreal Engine 4
I launched onto phones
It mostly crashes at startup. Then sometimes it works a little bit, then crashes.
I found a log and attached it below
The main thing says NULL POINTER DEREFERENCE, I'm not sure how to fix that in UE4

LOG STARTS:

Process: com.example.game
PID: 30736
Flags: 0x30c8be44
Package: com.example.game v52 (2.1)
Foreground: Yes
Build: BLU/BLU_G5/G0030:9/PPR1.180620.011/47349:user/release-keys

---

Native Crash TIME: 13663417

---

Build fingerprint: 'BLU/BLU_G5/G0350:9/PPR1.180620.011/47349:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
pid: 30736, tid: 30770, name: GameThread  >>> com.example <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0

**Cause: null pointer dereference**

```
x0  0000007636ff3400  x1  0000000000000000  x2  0000000000000001  x3  ffffffffa00e6a63
x4  001d0ac365000000  x5  0000000000000000  x6  00000076e8dd5000  x7  00000000001b8a32
x8  000000000000000a  x9  000000000000000a  x10 000000763967cc00  x11 000000763bc74138
x12 0000000000000018  x13 000000005ff1cafb  x14 002d6de553a20d9c  x15 00005e7a25d77b4e
x16 0000007647dc3de0  x17 00000076e6e44a10  x18 0000000012e431e0  x19 0000007636ff3400
x20 0000007647ea20b8  x21 0000000000000000  x22 00000076491df588  x23 0000000000000001
x24 0000007647e9e000  x25 0000007647e9e000  x26 00000076491df588  x27 0000007647e9e000
x28 0000007647e9e614  x29 00000076491da2e0
sp  00000076491da260  lr  000000764448d28c  pc  000000764448d860
```

backtrace:

```
#00 pc 0000000005494860  /data/app/com.example-3XbOYcKBOswdKKougXbCXA==/lib/arm64/libUE4.so (offset 0x4b3a000) (TProperty<FFieldPath, FProperty>::ClearValueInternal(void*) const+48)

#01 pc 0000000005494288  /data/app/com.example-3XbOYcKBOswdKKougXbCXA==/lib/arm64/libUE4.so (offset 0x4b3a000) (FLinkerLoad::FinishExternalReadDependencies(double)+40)

#02 pc 0000000005470bd8  /data/app/com.example-3XbOYcKBOswdKKougXbCXA==/lib/arm64/libUE4.so (offset 0x4b3a000) (FFindStronglyConnected::StrongConnectInner(UObject*)+1076)

#03 pc 0000000005471cbc  /data/app/com.example-3XbOYcKBOswdKKougXbCXA==/lib/arm64/libUE4.so (offset 0x4b3a000) (IncrementalPurgeGarbage(bool, float)+1220)

#04 pc 0000000005472490  /data/app/com.example-3XbOYcKBOswdKKougXbCXA==/lib/arm64/libUE4.so (offset 0x4b3a000) (UnhashUnreachableObjects(bool, float)+20)
```

Comment: If it crashes with a null point reference, then somewhere in your code, you're accessing an uninitialized reference (probably an actor, component or module). Does it happen with any particular action you can reproduce?

Comment: Hey thanks. Are you familiar with Unreal Engine? I have tried to narrow it down with a lot of trial and error, but have not found it yet.